# Excel type of input sheet that allows new cols to be added

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for some type of mvc3/jquery functional grid that allows new cols and rows to be added and then allow values entered per cell. Something like the following screen shot below.

The view soesn't have to be excel like where numbers are entered all at once then saved.  I think i will have users click in the cell and have a box popup so that when numbers are entered the value is saved immediately (not sure yet).

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Cool I am also looking for the same either free or commercial!

Comment: i'm trying to do the same thing but with java. what i do is handle user input like that in the view then pass everything to my servlet which transforms every row into an object. then i would have a collection of rows that i can now save into the database or do some error checking

Comment: Any other progress on this guys???...with what you are currently implementing?  How are you handing user input in the view?

Answer (score 0):

jQGrid http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx for MVC with some tweak in inline row edit feature might be useful.