# Host WPF window in browser

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc

Can an hosted WPF window in the web browser access the client's clipboard in both copy and paste? Has anybody tried to host a WPF window inside a ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

While still looking for an advanced grid for ASP.NET MVC which supports two-ways  MS Excel copy/paste and inline editing ( see question: [Excel type of input sheet that allows new cols to be added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800295/excel-type-of-input-sheet-that-allows-new-cols-to-be-added) ).

I start thinking that eventually I could host a WPF window in the web application but I am not 100% sure if such WPF form will have full access to the user clipboard.

Our web application will have many pages and this will not affect all of them; only some specific pages where users are expecting this feature will eventually contain the embedded/hosted WPF window with an advanced grid.

Quite an example is Google docs where without WPF, without any plugin or activeX you get inline editing and clipboard two wasy exactly as we also need.

... or should I tell the user to paste into google docs and then I connect to that google file via GDocs APIs and grab the pasted content? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WPF window is not possible. But WPF user controls or views are possible ...

you have 3 options

1. XBAP
2. Silverlight with out of browser (lonely popup app)
3. Loose XAML

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480223.aspx#wpfandwbas_topic6